# Is there a way to shim Lua 5.1 to support comparison meta methods?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Most versions of Lua support arithmetic comparison operators on tables. For example consider this scenario, simplified as an abstraction for handling lengths of various units:

```lua
local function convert_units (input)
    if type(input) ~= "table" then
        return input
    else
        if input.unit == "cm" then
            return input.amount * 10
        else
            return input.amount
        end
    end
end

local mt = {
    __lt = function (self, other)
        return convert_units(self) < convert_units(other)
    end
}

local a = {
    amount = 1.2,
    unit = "cm"
}

local b = {
    amount = 14,
    unit = "mm"
}

setmetatable(a, mt)
setmetatable(b, mt)

print(a < b)
```

This will output `true` because the meta table has a `__lt` method that casts the objects to be in compatible units, then compares them. This code will work in Lua 5.1, 5.2, and 5.3

The problem comes when you try to miss-match types like this:

```lua
print (a < 13)
```

This will work in Lua 5.2 and 5.3, but in Lua 5.1 it will throw an error:

> lua5.1: attempt to compare number with table

The math meta method is perfectly capable of handling the raw number on one side of the comparison, but Lua 5.1 refuses to even try.

Unfortunately I need to be able to support a range of Lua interpreters. With the lowest common denominator  being Lua 5.1, this is going to mean either always making the raw number site a similar object instantiation or always using `convert_units()` when writing comparisons.

Given the [volume and complexity of code involved](https://github.com/sile-typesetter/sile/pull/751) it would be really nice if I could shim Lua 5.1 to support this. Is there any way to convince it to allow comparing a table to a number?

Comment: You can solve the problem by using LuaJIT instead of vanilla Lua 5.1.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I wish! It would go a lot faster too ... but alas I have to support vanilla Lua 5.1. If I could just make the problem go away by forcing my preferred Lua interpreter there would be a lot of things I could take advantage of.

Comment: Lua authors have already dropped support of Lua 5.1.  Currently, there are some number of known bugs in Lua 5.1, but these bugs will never be fixed!  Lua team recommends to upgrade your Lua. Why are you still supporting Lua 5.1?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Because it rears its ugly head as the default Lua interpreter preinstalled on some platforms that are still more popular than one would hope. Believe me I wish this were not the case, it's kind of a sore subject with me.

Comment: Usually Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2 are two different packages and can coexist on the same machine if you renamed executables (both are `lua` by default).

Comment: BTW, there is another syntax available in Lua 5.1: `a "<" (b)`, involving `__call` metamethod.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I don't control the hosts the code has to run on. I'm quite well aware most platforms _have_ ways to get a newer Lua interpreter into the picture, but I can't require that (yet, I'm counting the days). In the mean time it would be interesting to see your writeup on using alternate comparison syntax as an answer, I don't follow 100% yet.

Comment: `mt.__call = function(a, op) if op == "<" then return function(b) return LT(a, b) end end end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid it's impossible. It might help if you compare the implementation of `luaV_lessthan` for 5.1 and 5.3:

```
int luaV_lessthan (lua_State *L, const TValue *l, const TValue *r) {
  int res;
  if (ttype(l) != ttype(r))
    return luaG_ordererror(L, l, r);
  else if (ttisnumber(l))
    return luai_numlt(nvalue(l), nvalue(r));
  else if (ttisstring(l))
    return l_strcmp(rawtsvalue(l), rawtsvalue(r)) < 0;
  else if ((res = call_orderTM(L, l, r, TM_LT)) != -1)
    return res;
  return luaG_ordererror(L, l, r);
}
```

5.3:

```
int luaV_lessthan (lua_State *L, const TValue *l, const TValue *r) {
  int res;
  if (ttisnumber(l) && ttisnumber(r))  /* both operands are numbers? */
    return LTnum(l, r);
  else if (ttisstring(l) && ttisstring(r))  /* both are strings? */
    return l_strcmp(tsvalue(l), tsvalue(r)) < 0;
  else if ((res = luaT_callorderTM(L, l, r, TM_LT)) < 0)  /* no metamethod? */
    luaG_ordererror(L, l, r);  /* error */
  return res;
}
```

As you can see, when executing the `lessthan` function, which gets emited as a result of spotting `<` in the code, those implementations do vastly different things. When the old interpreter sees operands of different types, it bails out very quickly. So there's simply no way of making an unwrapped number compare to a table.